# How do I iterate over all the lines output by a command in zsh?

Tags: iteration, zsh, lines

How do I iterate over all the lines output by a command using zsh, without setting IFS?

The reason is that I want to run a command against every file output by a command, and some of these files contain spaces.

Eg, given the deleted file:

```
foo/bar baz/gamma
```

That is, a single directory 'foo', containing a sub directory 'bar baz', containing a file 'gamma'.

Then running:

```
git ls-files --deleted | xargs ls
```

Will report in that file being handled as two files: 'foo/bar', and '/baz/gamma'.

I need it to handle it as *one* file: 'foo/bar baz/gamma'.

Comment: does your system have the xargs command?

Comment: @lunixboches: Yes, it does - however, it still fails to handle the lines properly.

Comment: `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 ls` will use null (\0) separators instead of whitespace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `tr` and the `-0` option of `xargs`, assuming that the lines don't contain `\000` (NUL), which is a fair assumption due to NUL being one of the characters that can't appear in filenames:

```
git ls-files --deleted | tr '\n' '\000' | xargs -0 ls
```

this turns the line: `foo/bar baz/gamma\n` into `foo/bar baz/gamma\000` which `xargs -0` knows how to handle

Comment: Can't get better than that, thanks! (And it works in bash, too!)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to run the command once for all the lines:

```
ls "${(@f)$(git ls-files --deleted)}"
```

The `f` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) means to split the command's output on newlines. There's a more general form `(@s:||:)` to split at an arbitrary string like `||`. The `@` flag means to retain empty records. Somewhat confusingly, the whole expansion needs to be inside double quotes, to avoid `IFS` splitting on the output of the [command substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution), but it will produce separate words for each record.

If you want to run the command for each line in turn, the portable idiom isn't particularly complicated:

```
git ls-filed --deleted | while IFS= read -r line; do ls $line; done
```

If you want to run the command as few times as the command line length limit permits, use [zargs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs).

```
autoload -U zargs
zargs -- "${(@f)$(git ls-files --deleted)}" -- ls
```

Comment: Thanks for that - there's lots of useful information here but I think xargs is still more efficient because it will run one command for each group of files. (What if I have so many files that won't fit on the args list?)

Comment: @Arafangion `zargs` is like `xargs` (runs as few instances as possible while fitting inside the command line length limit), only with a reasonable interface.